# Updating variable value with ng-submit

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my app, I have `Quantity: {{num}}`.  I have a default value of 3 declared by scope. The goal is to press:

```
<form ng-submit="addContact()">
        <input class="btn-primary" type="submit" value="Add Contact">
</form>
```

and update the count.  However, it does not.

Here is what I have in my controller:

```
app.controller("MainController", function($scope){
    var count = 3;
    $scope.num = count;
    $scope.addContact = function()
    {
        count += 1;
        console.log(count);
    }
});
```

I can see the count in the console, but I don't see it updating within the DOM.  What am I missing?

Comment: can you add plunker for your problem?

Comment: Do `$scope.num += 1` instead of incrementing `count`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you just copied `count` into `$scope.num`. So if you increment `count`, it won't affect `$scope.num`.

Try incrementing `$scope.num`

```
app.controller("MainController", function($scope){
    $scope.num = 3;
    $scope.addContact = function()
    {
        $scope.num += 1;
        console.log($scope.num);
    }
});
```

**[DEMO PLUNKER](http://plnkr.co/edit/oj8ZyhEj5MH1iOYW54oZ?p=preview)**

Comment: Wow, that simple.  `scope` is scaring me a lot more than it should.  I guess that's why I didn't touch it.  Thanks!